# Do I remove webpack-dev-server and hot-module middleware code during production build, or when I get ready for production?

Tags: javascript, webpack, hot-module-replacement

As the title suggests, when I'm ready to host the code for production, should I remove all usages of `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` from my server code as they are `dev-dependencies`? What's the best way to set this up so maybe I don't have to worry about this?

This is a snapshot of my server code:

```
// webpack -> HMR
const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackConfig = require("../webpack.config");
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

// webpack HMR init
app.use(
    require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
        noInfo: false,
        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    })
);
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));

...

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const initialContent = await serverRender();
    res.render("index", {
        ...initialContent,
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Express application listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Angular uses WebPack for its builds.  In Angular, you just do `ng build -prod`, then copy your app (now sans WebPack dependencies) from `./dist`.  It sounds like your project is in NodeJS?  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054082/) or [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack/).

Comment: @paulsm4 This isn't angular. HMR is not exclusively associated with angular. It's Webpack. Webpack is used all over the place.

Comment: I know that.  I was just mentioning the one context I've used WebPack, hoping it might suggest something helpful to the OP.  Q: Do you have any idea what the OP is using WebPack for (you assumed "expressJS", which implies "NodeJS")?  Q: The OP has hard-coded webpack dependencies in his app.  Can these be parameterized (and hence "eliminated" from a "production build")?  Q: What about the other hard-coded dependencies, for the "middleware" and "hot module loading"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your HMR code (or really, any development/environment specific setting) into it's own area. I wouldn't recommend taking it out of your code as you may come back to the application and want to update something. Having HMR is a pretty nice luxery, so I would just have you code sniff out the environment, and if it's development, run the associated code. Otherwise, don't run it.

[How do you detect the environment in an express.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449665/how-do-you-detect-the-environment-in-an-express-js-app)

Comment: So something like this: `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ...HMR init code...}`?

Comment: I think you want if it's NOT production. HMR isn't a use case in production, only dev.